# Prove that family of subsets is the set of cosets of some subroup of group

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

**Exercise**
Let $G$ be a finite group and suppose that $\mathbf{C}$ is a family of subsets of a group $G$ which for a partition of $G$. Further suppose that $gC \in \mathbf{C}$ for any $g \in G$ and $C \in \mathbf{C}$

> Prove that $\mathbf{C}$ is a set of cosets of some subgroup of $G$

**Solution**

So basically I need to show that all elements of $\mathbf{C}$ have same cardinality, $1 \in C \in \mathbf{C}$ is a group and all elements of $\mathbf{C}$ are of the form $gC$ for some $g$.(Correct me if I am wrong)

Cardinality:
Pick arbitraty $C_i,C_j \in \mathbf{C}$. Since $\mathbf{C}$ form a partition they both are non empty. Hence $\exists a,b \in G$ such that $a \in C_i, b \in C_j$. By "Further suppose that $gC \in \mathbf{C}$ for any $g \in G$ and $C \in \mathbf{C}$ 
" we know that $ab^{-1} C_r \in \mathbf{C}$ and $(ab^{-1})b=a \in C_r$. Hence it follows that $|C_r|=|C_j|$ because each element of G is contained in exactly one element of $\mathbf{C}$.

Please correct me if I am wrong. Proving that $1 \in C \in \mathbf{C}$
 I am quite sure, however not sure how to prove last part, that is "all elements of $C$ are of the form $gC$ for some $g$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find or construct the subgroup that produces these alleged cosets. If they were indeed cosets, the part of the partition that contains $1$ must be that subgroup. Then, by the hypotheses of the problem, every left coset of this subgroup must be a part of the partition, which forces the partition to consist *only* of left cosets. So, all you really need to do is prove that, if $1 \in C \in \mathbf{C}$, then $C$ is a subgroup.

Suppose $x, y \in C$. Note that $1 = x^{-1} x \in x^{-1}C \in \mathbf{C}$, and given $\mathbf{C}$ is a partition, $x^{-1} C = C$. Thus, $x^{-1} y \in x^{-1} C = C$, proving $C$ is a subgroup, as required.

**EDIT:** By request, here is the full proof:

Suppose $G$ is a group, and $\mathbf{C}$ is a partition of $G$ that is closed under left multiplication by elements of $G$. That is, if $C \in \mathbf{C}$ and $g \in G$, then $gC \in \mathbf{C}$. (Note that the definition of partition requires that $\emptyset \notin \mathbf{C}$.)

We wish to show that there exists a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $\mathbf{C}$ is the set of left cosets of $H$. That is, we must find a subgroup $H$ such that, $gH \in \mathbf{C}$ for all $g \in G$, and for any $C \in \mathbf{C}$, there exists a $g \in G$ such that $C = gH$.

Since $\mathbf{C}$ partitions $G$, we have $1 \in G = \bigcup \mathbf{C}$, hence there must be some $C \in \mathbf{C}$ such that $1 \in C$. As you and I have both shown, this is a subgroup of $G$. Let $H = C$.

So, since $H \in \mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ is closed under left multiplication, we know that $gH \in \mathbf{C}$ for all $g \in G$. That is, $\mathbf{C}$ contains all left cosets of $gH$.

On the other hand, suppose $C \in \mathbf{C}$. We wish to show it is a left coset. Since $C \neq \emptyset$, choose $g \in C$. Then, $g^{-1}C \in \mathbf{C}$, and
$$1 = g^{-1} g \in g^{-1}C \cap H,$$
so $g^{-1} C \cap H \neq \emptyset$. Since these sets are parts in a partition, we must have
$$g^{-1} C = H \implies gg^{-1} C = gH \implies C = gH.$$
So, every $C \in \mathbf{C}$ is a left coset of $H$, completing the proof.

(We did not need to show that the cardinalities of the parts are the same. This can be deduced from the proven fact that the parts are all left cosets of the same subgroup.)

Comment: As I have mentioned I am quite sure how to prove the subgroup part, however my question is: Is that all that I need to show?

Comment: Also is my proof for cardinality part correct?

Comment: Well, you need to observe, as I said, that all left cosets of this subgroup $H$ are parts in your partition. But, the set of all left cosets already cover the group. If $C \in \mathbf{C}$, then pick any $g \in C$, and $g \in gH \in \mathbf{C}$. Hence, $C \cap gH \neq \emptyset \implies C = gH$, i.e. every part in the partition is a coset.

Comment: As for the cardinality proof, I'm not really clear on the logic there. What's $C_r$, and what happened to $C_i$?

Comment: $C_r$ is some other element of $\mathbf{C}$...

Comment: Please, could you write the proof, except the part that $\mathbf{C}$ is a subgroup. This part is clear, but I am really confused about other part of the proof. I mean I am confused about the structure cause I am not very good in constructing the proofs

Comment: I've got a meeting with my supervisor soon, but I'll make an edit soon after.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @MariyaKav Done.

Comment: Thank you so much everything is clear!

Answer (score 0):

Let H be the set in C containing e.
Then for any x in H, xH=H( since hH intersect H), which shows that H is a subgroup.
Now all the left  cosets of H must be in C, by assumption.
But the all left cosets of H forms a partition already. Thus the set C is the set of all the left coset of H.